# Is it possible to create a new line in eclipse console via text from a text file?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

```java
try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(factFind)); //location of text file
      String fileCon;
      while((fileCon = br.readLine()) != null) {
      factarray.add(fileCon);  //factarray is an arraylist 
      }
}
String[] factarray1 = factarray.toArray(new String [0]); // creating an array from arraylist
System.out.println("\nFact-" + randni + "\n");
System.out.println(factarray1[randn]);
```

How do I make this text line create a new line in the running console (\n does not seem to work)

Comment: println automatically adds a newline.

Comment: ```System.out.println``` already print line in console , you can explain more what is your problem please. the line ```System.out.println("\nFact-" + randni + "\n");``` is not show on the console ?

Comment: Did you **really** mean the Eclipse (OSGi) Console, the terminal or the java application console?